# Display whether or not a join exists for an entry

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

`members`: contains a list of members; each member has an `id` (and other fields).
`groups`: links members to groups. It has only two columns: `id_member` and `id_group`. A member can be part of 0, 1, or several groups. So for each member, there will be 0, 1, or more rows in this table.

I want to display a list of all members (regardless of the groups they are in), but at the same time I'm interested in two groups specifically (id 4 and 5), and for each member, I would like to display **whether or not** they are part of those two groups.

Ideally, my output would look like:

```
// example for one row
array(
   id => 1234,
   is_in_group4 => 1, // boolean
   is_in_group5 => 0, // boolean
)
```

And of course I would like to avoid to have duplicate members.

`is_in_groupX` are not columns that exist in the database, so they would have to be somehow created within the query. (I have no idea how, or if it is possible.)

My starting request is very simple:

```
SELECT
    distinct(members.id)
FROM
    members
INNER JOIN groups
    ON members.id = groups.id
```

... but I have no idea where to go from here.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you want all members regardless of whether they are in any groups then you might want a left join instead of an inner join.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson thanks, I'll look into it.